# Elasticsearch avoiding maxClauseCount error in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that contains the following documents in Elasticsearch 5.X.
It holds the string of a line of a document file as a single record.

```
{"file_id":"file0001", "row_id":"1", "text":"(text field to search...)"}
{"file_id":"file0001", "row_id":"2", "text":"(text field to search...)"}
{"file_id":"file0001", "row_id":"3", "text":"(text field to search...)"}
{"file_id":"file0002", "row_id":"1", "text":"(text field to search...)"}
{"file_id":"file0002", "row_id":"2", "text":"(text field to search...)"}
...Millions of documents...
```

And send the following query to extract the top 500 hit rows for each file.

```
{
   "_source":[
      "file_id",
      "text"
   ],
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query"{
            "must":{
               "regexp":{
                  "text":".*[o2].*"
               }
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "terms":{
               "file_id":[
                  (Thousands of file_ids...)
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "top-docs":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"file_id",
            "size":5000
         },
         "aggs":{
            "top_file_hits":{
               "top_hits":{
                  "size":500,
                  "highlight":{
                     "pre_tags":["<em>"],
                     "post_tags":["</em>"],
                     "fields":{
                        "text":{}
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then the following error is returned.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "too_many_clauses",
        "reason" : "maxClauseCount is set to 1024"
```

I consider the aggs process heavy, but I can't think of a way not to use it.
Any ideas?

Comment: In Elasticsearch 5, index.query.bool.max_clause_count has been deprecated/removed.

Insert in your elasticsearch.yml file indices.query.bool.max_clause_count : n instead (where n - new supported number of clauses). you can specify n as 4096

Comment: Thank for comment. I changed max_clause_count to 4096, but I got the error "maxClauseCount is set to 4096". I am aware that there is a fundamental problem with the query.

Comment: try increasing to double of 4096...